# descriptive statistics of each country in a panel data

Tags: stata

I have a panel dataset at firm and country level, as below:

```
Firm_ID year    FirmA_Q FirmB   FirmC   etc…    CountryA    CountryB    CountryC    etc…
1   1990                                
1   1991                                
1   1992                                
1   1993                                
1   1994                                
1   1995                                
2   1990                                
2   1991                                
2   1992                                
2   1993                                
2   1994                                
2   1995                                
etc…    etc…
```

Do you know how to create a descriptive statistics table like below and then export to MS Word?

In this table, the country is the column and the country-character variable is the row. They got the mean of each country-character variable for each country and the number of observations.
Besides, at the bottom, they have the Total obs. Mean(firm-year level) and Mean (country-level).

Could you please give me some suggestions?

I have tried to use

```
bys Country: asdoc sum CountryA County CountryC, stat(mean) replace
```

But I cannot get the number of observations on the right and bottom.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `help collapse` and `help tabstat` for obtaining mean values and other statistics. It'll be easier to help if you can provide a reproducible data example, as what has been provided isn't in a format that is particularly helpful for those trying to assist you.

Comment: @Cybernike is correct. It seems like there is a question in here that would be answerable, but right now it's not clear. [Please read the "About" section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info)  and create a real data extract using `dataex` from ssc. Then you'll probably get an answer quickly.

Comment: The comments above are bang on. Stata beginners (and some more advanced users) often waste a lot of time searching for a command that will give them exactly the table they want. If it's a one-off table, as it usually is, it can be much more efficient to get results from different commands and then edit the results into the form you want in a familiar environment (evidently MS Word in your case). Otherwise exactly the table you want will always be programmable -- by the command you write yourself for the purpose...